# Navigating through custom post types in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, content-management-system

I want to redesign my website using WordPress (as CMS) and Bootstrap (as front-end).

Now, I've been pretty successful at doing so, but I have one specific problem.

I have a tutorial website and I want the navigation structure to look like this :

If the user is on my `'website-name/tutorials'` then display to him all of the tutorial series titles in an unordered list (so for example C++, XHTML and CSS - but not individual tutorials in each series)...

If the user clicks on some specific serie, then display an ordered list of the elements (so, if he clicks C++, then URL will be `'website-name/tutorials/cplusplus'` and he will be able to see all of the tutorial in an ordered list).

If the clicks on one specific tutorial, then the URL goes (for example) `'website-name/tutorials/cplusplus/installing-the-program'` and user gets all the content related to the tutorial.

Now, I have been experimenting with this and concluded that the best solution is to create custom post type named "Tutorial" and then make every single tutorial that post type.

However, since on `'website-name/tutorials/cplusplus'` I want to display the list of tutorials in "C++" tutorial series and on `'website-name/tutorials'` I want to display only the tutorial names, I don't know how to do that.

I tried to do that using Hiearchical posts (so, for example, I made a parent post named "C++" and it's children were all of the tutorials in the C++ serie).

However, I have a problem with that, because my C++ tutorial series has 100 tutorials, but it shows me 101 list elements (I made the website display all the custom post types in an ordered list), with the first one on the list being C++ (the parent post).

So, I'd like to echo the series name only on the `'website-name/tutorials'` not on the beginning of the list.

I researched and people seem to use archive in custom post types, rather than parent/child system for this kind of navigation.

I just wanted some of the WP experienced users here to tell me, which is the better solution for my problem? Dealing with these parent/child problems or switching from parent/child posts to archive posts?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand fully perhaps using standard posts and categories will do the trick? Your '/tutorials/' page can display the full list of all posts and when a user clicks on a specific category (e.g. C++) only the relevant posts will display.

You can use the following code to list posts of a specific category:

```
<?php query_posts( 'cat=20' ); ?>
```

Changing "20" with the chosen category ID.

Hope this helps!